# Vue 2 make a div Clickable and image

Tags: vuejs2, vue-component

I am playing around with Vue 2, and I want to make a whole div clickable. 
This div have a link, image and text.

I used router-link for links in header and other links but when I try to use something else the page keeps refreshing.

Can someone please help me get over this somehow..

Cheers!

Comment: Can you add relevant code or create a fiddle of it?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Add click event to you `<div>` that you want to be clickable as below:

```
<div @click="clickMethod"></div>
```

Now in your methods property add rhe **clickMethod** callback that you want to fire when clicked like below

```
methods: {
    clickMethod() {
        //add code that you wish to happen on click
  }
}:
```

Comment: Thank you for your help :) I appreciate it. Since we are here, can I ask you another question please. If I use Vuex State, can the client from browser somehow access the State value since I want to pass some "sensitive" data there, but I am not sure if If someone can access it's value from Console unless I use getters to pass the value into DOM ? Looking forward to receive from you or someone :)

Comment: What kind of sensitive data?

Answer (score 5):

For anyone who is stuck here like I did on how to make a Div Clickable

```
<div @click="clickeMethod">
<p> Some Text Here </p>
</div>
```

script:

```
<script>
export default {
  name: 'headers',
  data() {
    return {

    };
  },
  methods: {
    clickMethod() {
      this.$router.push('home');
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

This Event will make a div Clickable.

Hope I helped someone :) and thnx to @user7814783

Comment: What if you have clickable links inside the div? I want to make a div clickable but allow the user to click links inside that div without triggering the click event on the div itself.

Answer (score 0):

For those wondering how `router.push` method works, below are various ways you can use the method:

```
// literal string path
router.push('home')

// object
router.push({ path: 'home' })

// named route
router.push({ name: 'user', params: { userId: '123' } })

// with query, resulting in /register?plan=private
router.push({ path: 'register', query: { plan: 'private' } })
```

For me this implementation worked best:

```
<script>
export default {
  name: 'home',
  data() {
    return {

    };
  },
  methods: {
    clickMethod() {
      this.$router.push({ path: 'home' });
    },
  },
};
</script>
```